# Como usar ellipsis css3?

Tags: css, css3

Estou tentando e estou fazendo igual explica na w3schools mas não esta dando certo.

```css
.box {
    width: 250px; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Maecenas fermentum   nisi ut auctor posuere. Fusce pulvinar blandit commodo.
 Nulla nunc nunc, ultrices vitae aliquam sit amet, aliquam a metus. Aenean 
semper nisi sed augue elementum tincidunt. Maecenas sit amet magna id lectus
tempor luctus in quis justo. Proin vel iaculis.
</div>
```

Comment: Eu estava atrás disso faz um bom tempo e encontrei esse exemplo, caso queira dar uma olhada http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iBtep

Comment: Obrigado, muito bom esse exemplo e funcional, mas p/ o meu caso eu so posso fazer alteração no css  acredito que o exemplo do @Ack Lay vai me atender melhor mas a sua solução pode ajudar outros usuarios, parabens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Além do `text-overflow: ellipsis`, você ainda deve usar a propriedade [***`white-space`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), que define como o espaço em branco dentro de um elemento é manipulado. Também a propriedade [***`overflow`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) como *hidden*, que especifica quando o conteúdo de um elemento de nível de bloco deve ser cortado. Veja como deve ficar seu código:

```css
.box { 
max-width: 250px;
font-size: 20dp;
white-space: nowrap;                  
overflow: hidden; /* "overflow" value must be different from "visible" */
text-overflow:    ellipsis;
border: 1px solid #ccc;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Maecenas fermentum   nisi ut auctor posuere. Fusce pulvinar blandit commodo.
 Nulla nunc nunc, ultrices vitae aliquam sit amet, aliquam a metus. Aenean 
semper nisi sed augue elementum tincidunt. Maecenas sit amet magna id lectus
tempor luctus in quis justo. Proin vel iaculis.
</div>
```

Também é possível fazer multilinhas usando o `webkit`. Veja abaixo um exemplo com 3 linhas:

```css
.box { 
  display: block; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-size: 20dp;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Maecenas fermentum   nisi ut auctor posuere. Fusce pulvinar blandit commodo.
     Nulla nunc nunc, ultrices vitae aliquam sit amet, aliquam a metus. Aenean 
    semper nisi sed augue elementum tincidunt. Maecenas sit amet magna id lectus
    tempor luctus in quis justo. Proin vel iaculis.
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Para quebrar na primeira linha você precisa adicionar as seguintes propriedades também:

```
{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Caso o contrário o seu texto vai quebrar para a linha de baixo e continuar infinitamente.

Comment: Ok certo... mas nao da para eu usar os 3 pontos  na terceira linha do texto...ou seja esse recurso é somente para a primeira linha ?

Comment: Depois dá primeira linha só com javascript. Esse recurso só funciona na primeira

Answer (score 4):

Seguindo o exemplo que menciona, ficou faltando 2 regras :

```
.box {
        width: 250px;
        white-space: nowrap; 
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden; 
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<style>
    .box {
        width: 250px; 
        text-overflow: ellipsis; 
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    
    /* acrescente */
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
<div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Maecenas fermentum   nisi ut auctor posuere. 
    Fusce pulvinar blandit commodo. 
    Nulla nunc nunc, ultrices vitae aliquam sit amet, aliquam a metus. 
    Aenean semper nisi sed augue elementum tincidunt. Maecenas sit amet magna id lectus tempor luctus in quis justo. 
    Proin vel iaculis.

</div>

<script>
    function mostrarTituloPor_AllyssonAlvesFrontEnd(){
        var box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
        for(var i = 0; i< box.length; i++){
            var conteudo = box[i].textContent;
            box[i].setAttribute('title', conteudo);
        }
      };
  
      mostrarTituloPor_AllyssonAlvesFrontEnd();
  
</script>
```